# Performing Cokriging in R?

Tags: raster, r, ndvi, kriging

I would like to perform cokriging of 60 observed data points. In the shapefile, there are 60 fields containing the observations as Time 1 to Time 60.

I also have 60 rasters in tiff format. I want to perform cokriging for each raster versus points. The expected output would be cokriged raster dataset.

In R, I can perform the following:

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(raster)

setwd("C:\\somepath")

#open Shapefile

data <- readOGR("C:\\somepath\\file.shp", "file")
proj4string(data)=CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

#open Raster and Stack
r<- raster()

temp <- stack(list.files(path = "C:\\somepath", pattern 
='temp*.*.tif',full.names = T))
```

I am stuck after this. I know that I should do some **overlay, variogram fitting, goodness of fit, and validation** but I do not know how.

Comment: Please do not include unnecessary thanks in your questions (or answers) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just point out that there is no way that this specific data meets the 
"coregionalized variable theory" assumption underlying cokriging. This is to say that the data is shown to have a multivariate spatial cross-correlation as well as univariate spatial autocorrelation (exhibiting the same semivariance).

You may want to look into some of the [glm geostatistical approaches](https://www.r-project.org/conferences/DSC-2003/Proceedings/RibeiroEtAl.pdf) in the geoR and geoRglm package(s) that avoid this assumption. I would also suggest the [geostatsp](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v063i12) package which uses a Bayesian approach via INLA and supports Gaussian and non-Gaussian process.

Comment: Hi, @JeffreyEvans: thanks for your comments. This is insightful. Although, I would like to push through with the question thinking that similar issue (albeit not using NDVI vs Soil Moisture) may be raised in GIS SE in the future. This link seems to raise a lot of errors in R: http://r-video-tutorial.blogspot.kr/2011/04/cokriging-with-gstat-videotutorial.html

Comment: @user2543 There is a very good reason that you do not see cokriging commonly utilized in the literature. It is very difficult to meet the underlying assumptions and many consider it an invalid method. So, "pushing through" is somewhat irrelevant as, geostatistical GML and regression Kriging has pretty  much supplanted this method.